# "tcsetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device" when redirecting output to console

Tags: linux, console, stdout, stderr, redirect

When redirecting stdout and stderr to a console, I'm getting(?):


tcsetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device

tcesetattr ICANON: Inappropriate ioctl for device

tcsetattr ~ICANON: Inappropriate ioctl for device


using: **${DTNG_EXEC} ${DTNG_LOG_FILE} > /dev/tty2 2>&1**


I've tried writing other example shell scripts and C/C++ programs to simplify the actual code and script BUT to no avail. All the examples work as expected ... writing stdout and stderr to the console without error.


BTW, I searched on **tcesetattr** and found naught.  It defaulted to **tcsetattr**.

Comment: Do you mean that other commands are able to print on /dev/tty2 ? From what tty are you running your script ? Who controls /dev/tty2 ? is there a getty process ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a simple piece of C code to output to both stdout and stderr.  Then used: ./a.out > /dev/tty2 2>&1 in my simple script. This works without problems.